# Git pull and stash on production server

Tags: php, git, laravel, ubuntu

I'm using Git as version control tool in my project. Everything works fine in development environment, but, when I deploy, every time I'm asked to commit/stash changes.

```
remote: Counting objects: 20, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 20 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (20/20), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/myaccount/myproject
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 14b5cbd..7092c02
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I'm using the following command to get the changes:

```
sudo git pull https://myuser@bitbucket.org/myaccount/myproject.git
```

So, everytime I need to `sudo git stash` and pull again.

I think this happens because I need to change permissions of some directories after each pull, but I'm not sure if it is the root of the problem.

Anyway, this does not seem to be right. How can I pull the changes in my production server without needing to do this?

Comment: befor `git pull` , check `git status` and find the difference.

Comment: If changes of file permissions are tracked by git, how can I pull new code without stashing everything?

Comment: @Marvin I never change anything in the files, only permissions.

Comment: You probably forgot to ignore some folder that changes by runtime or command line tools. Another possibility is that you run `composer update`, you should run `composer install` instead to not change composer.lock

Answer (score 1):

Changes of file permissions are tracked by git.

You can change the permission of your file and commit it once and for all.